# Как запретить WebView приложению кэшировать сайт

Tags: webview, кэширование, android-webview, cache-control

У меня есть `WebView` приложение на основе сайт, который постоянно обновляется, но проблема в том, что когда зашёл в приложение, сайт сохранился в кэш, и, например, после обновления этого сайт, он не отобразится в приложении, а отобразилась его кэш версия, т. е. устаревшая версия сайт.

Помогите решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого можете использовать след настройки

```
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Так же можете удалять кэш с устройства перед загрузкой страницы

```
mWebView.clearCache(true)
```